# Highchart multiply data in tooltip

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I want to drop multiple data into 1 tooltip. Shared is false, this is correct. One line should only show its own value.

```
series: [
        {
            name: 'Installation',
            data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175, 43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175],
            data2: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
            data3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
        }, 
        {
            name: 'Other',
            data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111, 12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274],
            data2: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
            data3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
        },
        ]
```

On code above I want to add a second and third data from a query.

```
tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/> Second: {point.data2} <br> Third: {point.data3}',
            },
```

How to add these 'point.data2' and 'point.data3' values into the tooltip? I get null as return.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to use pointFormatter instead of pointFormat: http://jsfiddle.net/km8bovdz/

Comment: Great, so I am posting it as an answer

Comment: And I will confirm it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of your chart you should be able to use pointFormatter instead of pointFormat and inside pointFormatter get your second and third data.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter

```
  tooltip: {
    pointFormatter: function() {
      console.log(this)
      var string = this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br>';
      string += 'Second: ' + this.series.options.data2[this.index] + '<br>';
      string += 'Third: ' + this.series.options.data3[this.index];
      return string;
    }
  },
```

You can find an example of a chart with pointFormatter in the link below:
http://jsfiddle.net/km8bovdz/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will return null, because your `data2` and `data3` arrays are not associated with the `point` in any way.

The `point` is within the data array, and additional data elements should be attached to each `point`, rather than each `series`.

You achieve this by making each data point an object in the data array, like this (subset of your posted data):

```
series: [{
  name: 'Installation',
  data: [{
    y: 43934,
    data2: 1,
    data3: 1
  }, {
    y: 52503,
    data2: 2,
    data3: 2
  }, {
    y: 57177,
    data2: 3,
    data3: 3
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Other',
  data: [{
    y: 12908,
    data2: 1,
    data3: 1
  }, {
    y: 5948,
    data2: 1,
    data3: 1
  }, {
    y: 8105,
    data2: 1,
    data3: 1
  }]
}]
```

Fiddle example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/smxqwc1y/

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. I've added Grzegorz Blachliński his response as the answer on my question. I see your code would also fit.